# Is there a way to make the keyboard player 2?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth

I know that if you plug in a controller after after the game starts and press START, you become a second player baby that flies around. I know this works with keyboard as P1 and controller as P2 and 2 controllers as P1 and P2 but I would like to know if there is a way to make it so that controller is P1 and keyboard is P2

Comment: Why does it matter?

Comment: @NoneOfYourBusiness Why it matters is "NoneOfYourBusiness".  ...Now that I've made that joke please don't change your username or ill look weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found this [guide](http://steamcommunity.com//sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=336852913) on SteamCommunity:

> Playing coop consumes your rightmost heart container, be it half a
>   heart or a full one Be it an evil heart or a soul heart
>
> Step 1 - Plug in controller
>   Step 2 - Open Isaac
>   Step 3 - Start playing Isaac with keyboard
>   Step 4 - Push start on controller
>
> Options allows keybinding so have a look at that Controller takes
>   control of player 2
>
> If you want to play with the controller for player 1
>
> Step 1 - Plug in controller
>   Step 2 - Open Isaac
>   Step 3 - Start playing Isaac with controller
>   Step 4 - Push Enter on Keyboard

Anyway I'm not sure this will work, the only thing that [McMillen](http://bindingofisaac.com/post/89016610314/be-careful-i-dont-wanna-lose-this-baby) says is:

> When you are playing Isaac, a friend/mom/soul mate can join you by pressing start on the 2nd controller (or 1st controller if you are playing with the keyboard).

He says nothing about a second player on the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

In *Binding of Isaac: Rebirth*, whatever device is used to start a game will control the main character. Whatever device is used afterwards will spawn the second player.

So to have the keyboard control the spawn, just start the game using a controller.

This *might* be changed during play when opening the pause menu and disconnecting the controller, then resuming with the keyboard and reconnecting the controller. I don't believe it works the other way around.